# Applying orderby to C# LINQ Inner join

Tags: c#, linq, join, inner-join

I am trying out C# LINQ Joins from [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx).

I am not able to apply order by on inner join even though it works with group join.

The data on which queries are run are:

```
    class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    }

    class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    // Specify the first data source.
    static List<Category> categories = new List<Category>()
    { 
        new Category(){Name="Beverages", ID=001},
        new Category(){ Name="Condiments", ID=002},
        new Category(){ Name="Vegetables", ID=003},
        new Category() {  Name="Grains", ID=004},
        new Category() {  Name="Fruit", ID=005}            
    };

    // Specify the second data source.
    static List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product{Name="Cola",  CategoryID=001},
        new Product{Name="Tea",  CategoryID=001},
        new Product{Name="Mustard", CategoryID=002},
        new Product{Name="Pickles", CategoryID=002},
        new Product{Name="Carrots", CategoryID=003},
        new Product{Name="Bok Choy", CategoryID=003},
        new Product{Name="Peaches", CategoryID=005},
        new Product{Name="Melons", CategoryID=005},
    };
```

**The desired output is** (list order by categories in brackets and then by product) :

```
Cola(Beverages)
Tea(Beverages)
Mustard(Condiments)
Pickles(Condiments)
Melons(Fruit)
Peaches(Fruit)
Bok Choy(Vegetables)
Carrots(Vegetables)
```

I was able to produce this output using `group-join` with `orderby` and 2nd `from-select` to deform group hierarchy and produce plain list as follows:

```
var listGroupJoinOrderBy =
            from category in categories
            join product in products on category.ID equals product.CategoryID into prodGroup
            from prod in prodGroup
            orderby category.Name, prod.Name  //first order by category name then product name
            select
            new
            {
                Category = category.Name,
                Product = prod.Name
            };
```

But then I am unable to produce this same output with `orderby` applied to inner join (that is group-join without `into` clause). I tried following variants:

**Variant #1**

```
var innerJoinOrderBy =
            from category in categories
            orderby category.Name    //orderby category name
            join product in products on category.ID equals product.CategoryID                
            orderby product.Name     //orderby product name
            select
            new
            {
                Category = category.Name,
                Product = product.Name
            };
```

**Variant #2**

```
var innerJoinOrderBy =
            from category in categories

            join product in products on category.ID equals product.CategoryID                
            orderby category.Name, product.Name     //orderby category first and then by product name
            select
            new
            {
                Category = category.Name,
                Product = product.Name
            };
```

However both variants give the same output as if no `orderby` is used, and produces the following output:

```
Cola (Beverages)
Tea (Beverages)
Mustard (Condiments)
Pickles (Condiments)
Carrots (Vegetables)
Bok Choy (Vegetables)
Peaches (Fruit)
Melons (Fruit)
```

**Q. How can I produce the desired output with `inner-join` and `orderby`?**

Anyway, to print the query result one can use following `foreach` (just change the query variable name) :

```
foreach (var product in simpleInnerJoin)
{
    Console.WriteLine(product.Product + " (" + product.Category + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second option should work fine

```
var innerJoinOrderBy =
            from c in categories
            join p in products on c.ID equals p.CategoryID
            orderby c.Name, p.Name
            select new {
                Category = c.Name,
                Product = p.Name
            };
```

Output:

```
[
    { Product="Cola", Category="Beverages" },
    { Product="Tea", Category="Beverages" },
    { Product="Mustard", Category="Condiments" },
    { Product="Pickles", Category="Condiments" },
    { Product="Melons", Category="Fruit" },
    { Product="Peaches", Category="Fruit" },
    { Product="Bok Choy", Category="Vegetables" },
    { Product="Carrots", Category="Vegetables" }
]
```

From your output I see that items go in their original order. Make sure you have applied `orderby` operator in query.

Comment: u mean to swap `product` and `category` in variant 2?

Comment: @Mahesha999 its working (I copy-pasted console output). Also you second approach works too. Make sure you have applied correct `orderby` operator

Answer (score 2):

Take the Orderby out of the main Linq and use

```
foreach (var product in simpleInnerJoin.Orderby(i=> i.Category.Name).ThenBy(i=>i.Product.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(product.Product + " (" + product.Category + ")");
}
```

I think this should give you the output you require.

Comment: man that was a bit heavy for me, those extension methods and lambdas :'( Cant this be done solely through LINQ query? Tho I appreciate this, dont delete your answer.

Comment: other option might be to add a second Linq I will add to my answer

Comment: @DavidMolyneux there is no need to use additional Method syntax for ordering - you can apply ordering directly in query. Also there is no need to write additional queries for ordering

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy removed that from the answer. I would personally prefer to keep the order by separate to the main join as you can then use the same join query with different order else where in the code.

Comment: @DavidMolyneux I would use single query, unless you will *really* need different ordering in several places. YAGNI :)